# Can you orderby slug in a taxonomy archive page using WP_Query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, templates, archives

In my taxonomy.php, my query is `

```
  $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );  
  $wpq = array ('posts_per_page' => -1, $term->taxonomy => $term->slug, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'slug');
  $loop = new WP_Query($wpq);`
```

It correctly retrieves the <strike>droids</strike> posts I am looking for, but does not `orderby` `slug`. I can't find `slug` as an option in the documentation any more, but I swear I have successfully used it before.

How do I make it so?

Edit: `'orderby' => 'name'` appears to work in 1 category but not in my other category (so far, there are only 2). I'm wondering if the category where it does work is just coincidence...

Comment: Alternatively, what I'm actually trying to achieve is sorting by title, but ignoring "An", "A", "The" etc in the title - so "The Good Wife" should sort under "G", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in WP 3.2.1. See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages under "Parameters" and "page_name".

I'm working on exactly the same thing, but it seems I'll need to resort to to a custom query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query